# Bad pages redirection

Tags: pages, login, htaccess, private

I have a wordpress web site with only a private pages (can only be viewed by logged users)

I use the below code in my theme functions.php to be redirected to login page each time a put the page URL on the browser.

```
add_action( 'wp', 'redirect_private_page_to_login' );
function redirect_private_page_to_login(){
    $queried_object = get_queried_object();
    if (
        isset( $queried_object->post_status ) &&
        'publish' === $queried_object->post_status &&
        ! is_user_logged_in()
    ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( wp_login_url( get_permalink( $queried_object->ID ) ) );
        exit;
    }
}
```

When i put my page URL on the browser

example : https://website.com/page1  I should be redirected
to :

https://website.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwebsite.com%2Fpage1%2F

It works but **Sometimes** i'm redirected to **https://website.com/index.php** . It happen frequently with Edge and safari browsers **(that is my issue)**.

I think something is wrong in the redirection of the pages. It probably come from my **.htaccess** . I want to share it with you and hope someone can help me with this.

**Note:** I use SecuPress as security plugin. i have also a subdomain that why you will find test.website.com in the .htaccess

HTACCESS

```
# BEGIN SecuPress no_x_powered_by
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset X-Powered-By
</IfModule>
# END SecuPress
# BEGIN SecuPress readme_discloses
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^(.*/)?(readme|changelog|debug)\.(txt|md|html|log)$ - [R=404,L,NC]
</IfModule>
# END SecuPress
# BEGIN SecuPress wp_version
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^readme\.html$ - [R=404,L,NC]
</IfModule>
# END SecuPress
# BEGIN SecuPress bad_url_access
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wp-includes/js/tinymce/wp-tinymce\.php$
    RewriteRule ^(php\.ini|wp-config\.php|wp-includes/.+\.php|wp-admin/(admin-functions|install|menu-header|setup-config|([^/]+/)?menu|upgrade-functions|includes/.+)\.php)$ [R=404,L,NC]
</IfModule>
# END SecuPress
# BEGIN SecuPress directory_listing
<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
    Options -Indexes
</IfModule>
# END SecuPress
# BEGIN SecuPress php_disclosure
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \=PHP[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12} [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>
# END SecuPress
# BEGIN SecuPress bad_file_extensions
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/.*\.(\.9|73i87a|386|aaa|abc|aepl|aru|atm|aut|bat|bhx|bin|bkd|blf|bll|bmw|boo|bps|bqf|breaking_bad|btc|buk|bup|bxz|ccc|ce0|ceo|cfxxe|chm|cih|cla|cmd|com|coverton|cpl|crinf|crjoker|crypt|crypted|cryptolocker|cryptowall|ctbl|cxq|cyw|czvxce|darkness|dbd|delf|dev|dlb|dli|dll|dllx|dom|drv|dx|dxz|dyv|dyz|ecc|enciphered|encrypt|encrypted|enigma|exe1|exe_renamed|exx|ezt|ezz|fag|fjl|fnr|fuj|fun|good|gzquar|ha3|hlp|hlw|hsq|hts|iva|iws|jar|kcd|kernel_complete|kernel_pid|kernel_time|keybtc@inbox_com|kimcilware|kkk|kraken|lechiffre|let|lik|lkh|lnk|locked|locky|lok|lol!|lpaq5|magic|mfu|micro|mjg|mjz|nls|oar|ocx|osa|ozd|p5tkjw|pcx|pdcr|pgm|php|php2|php3|pid|pif|plc|poar2w|pr|pzdc|qit|qrn|r5a|rdm|rhk|rna|rokku|rrk|rsc_tmp|s7p|scr|scr|shs|ska|smm|smtmp|sop|spam|ssy|surprise|sys|tko|tps|tsa|tti|ttt|txs|upa|uzy|vb|vba|vbe|vbs|vbx|vexe|vxd|vzr|wlpginstall|wmf|ws|wsc|wsf|wsh|wss|xdu|xir|xlm|xlv|xnt|xnxx|xtbl|xxx|xyz|zix|zvz|zzz)$ - [R=404,L,NC]
</IfModule>
# END SecuPress
# BEGIN SecuPress hotlink
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ [NC]
</IfModule>
# END SecuPress
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
# Protect wp-config.php
<files wp-config.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>
# Redirection to HTTPS
RewriteCond     %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://test.website.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://test.website.com$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://website.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://website.com$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.test.website.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.test.website.com$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.website.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.website.com$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://test.website.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://test.website.com$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://website.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://website.com$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www.test.website.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www.test.website.com$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www.website.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www.website.com$      [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp)$ - [F,NC]
# BEGIN MINIORANGE MEDIA RESTRICTION
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN MINIORANGE MEDIA RESTRICTION` and `END MINIORANGE MEDIA RESTRICTION` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*(png|jpg|pdf|doc|docx|xlsx|xls|mp4|ppt|pptx|mov|mpeg|avi|m4v|svg|wmv|bmp)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} protectedfiles 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule . - [R=403,L]
# END MINIORANGE MEDIA RESTRICTION
# BEGIN cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
# Manual editing of this file may result in unexpected behavior.
# To make changes to this file, use the cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor (Home >> Software >> MultiPHP INI Editor)
# For more information, read our documentation (https://go.cpanel.net/EA4ModifyINI)
<IfModule php7_module>
   php_value upload_max_filesize 25M
   php_value post_max_size 128M
   php_flag display_errors Off
   php_value max_execution_time 2000
   php_value max_input_time 600
   php_value max_input_vars 4000
   php_value memory_limit 512M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php74"
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
<IfModule lsapi_module>
   php_value upload_max_filesize 25M
   php_value post_max_size 128M
   php_flag display_errors Off
   php_value max_execution_time 2000
   php_value max_input_time 600
   php_value max_input_vars 4000
   php_value memory_limit 512M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php74"
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
# END cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php74” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Thanks you in advance for your help.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> # Redirection to HTTPS
> RewriteCond     %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
> RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
> ```

This rule is in the wrong place. It needs to go *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment marker. ie. Before the WordPress front-controller.

Currently, this will result in a redirect to `/index.php` if requesting HTTP.

> ```
> # BEGIN SecuPress hotlink
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
>     RewriteEngine On
>     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
>     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ [NC]
> </IfModule>
> # END SecuPress
> ```

And this block is incomplete/wrong. Unless you know the missing directives, this block must be deleted.

Fortunately, it's "only" making the next `RewriteRule` (in the WordPress code block) superfluous, but it could potentially break your site.

Comment: It works thanks. any idea to make this htaccess more secure?